# How do I add data to an <a> tag for use in Ajax Requests?

Tags: html, ajax

I would like to have a link with looks something like this: Call to Action.  However, if the javascript hasn't loaded completely and a user clicks that link, they will be redirected to a php script which spits out json.  Alternatively, I will likely do something along the lines of Call to Action.

Is this the best practice for handling this situation?

Comment: you need to show your code, also improve your reputation

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to put the data there with Javascript and then there is no timing mismatch.

```
<a id="link123" href="#">Call to Action</a>
```

with, say, jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#link123").click(function() {
    // get JSON, put the address ehre
  });
});
```

Comment: Returning false after the click event would be helpful too, it would prevent the browser from jumping to the top of the screen.

Comment: I wouldn't use a # as an href, ever. Use href="javascript:void(0)" or href="javascript://" ... that way nothing happens at all if the user clicks before the event listener is added.

Comment: So just store the data in the ID and then match it out? Doesn't seem very elegant

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to go with the metadata plugin for jquery.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata

Any reasons why this is a terrible idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, [link to a document which is the same as the current document would be after the transformation](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

It sounds like you are already overriding the normal link action, so (as far as the client is concerned) you probably just need to do something like adding `&type=json` to the URL before running it through XHR.